# fgetc to skip from point to new line

Tags: c, fgetc

I am trying to get fgetc to read through a file and skip from a certain indicator until a new line. This seems like a simple question, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Here is an example of my question:

```
read this in ; skip from semicolon on to new line
```

My best guess at a solution would be to read in the entire file, and for each line use strtok to skip from ; to the end of the line. Obviously this is horrible inefficient. Any ideas?

*I need to use fgetc or something like fgetc that will parse the file character by character

Comment: What do you do with the part of the string you want to keep?  read it in character by character?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `fgets` to read the entire line at a time?

Comment: With the text I keep I want to ideally read it in string by string (ie, character array seperated by whitespace). fgets can read the entire line up until a specified line length, but I am looking to read the characters up until ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is read the entire line in, then truncate if there a `;`.

```
char buffer[1024], * p ;

if ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fin) )
{
  if (( p= strchr( buffer, ';' ))) { *p = '\0' ; }  // chop off ; and anything after
  for ( p= buffer ; ( * p ) ; ++ p )
  {
    char c= * p ;
    // do what you want with each character c here.
  }
}
```

When you do the read, buffer will initially contain:

> "read this in ; skip from semicolon on to new line\n\0"

After you find the `;` in the line and stick a `'\0'` there, the buffer looks like:

> "read this in \0 skip from semicolon on to new line\n\0"

So the for loop starts at `r` and stops at the first `\0`.

Comment: the problem with doing this is that I need to use fgetc. I can only use fgetc on a file, as there is no "sgetc" in c, if I'm not mistaken?
Thanks!

Comment: That's because you don't need `sgetc`, I will expand my example.

Answer (score 0):

Given a requirement to use `fgetc()`, then you are probably supposed to echo everything up to the first semicolon on the line, and suppress everything from the semicolon to the end of the line. I note in passing that `getc()` is functionally equivalent to `fgetc()` and since this code is about to read from standard input and write to standard output, it would be reasonable to use `getchar()` and `putchar()`.  But rules are rules...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    bool read_semicolon = false;

    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            putchar(c);
            read_semicolon = false;
        }
        else if (c == ';')
            read_semicolon = true;
        else if (read_semicolon == false)
            putchar(c);
        /* else suppressed because read_semicolon is true */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't have C99 and `<stdbool.h>`, you can use `int`, `0` and `1` in place of `bool`, `false` and `true` respectively. You can use `else if (!read_semi_colon)` if you prefer.

Comment: this works but the problem is in order to use it I would need to make a new file to reprint everything minus the ;->. I might do this.

Comment: If you're not constrained to use `fgetc()`, which you aren't because you've accepted an answer that doesn't use `fgetc()`, then you don't need this code. The trouble is, your question was incomplete; you did not state what you needed to do with the data before the semicolon. Echoing to output is a simple option; stashing into an array that can be processed by some other function requires some modification of the code above. Incomplete specifications get incomplete answers; they're also apt to irritate people who try to help you. (I'm not too fussed; it didn't take me long to write that!)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Function of compatible fgets to read up to the character specified by a delimiter.
//However file stream keep going until to newline.
//s : buffer, n : buffer size
char *fgets_delim(char *s, int n, FILE *fp, char delimiter){
    int i, ch=fgetc(fp);

    if(EOF==ch)return NULL;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;++i, ch=fgetc(fp)){
        s[i] = ch;
        if(ch == '\n'){
            s[i+1]='\0';
            break;
        }
        if(ch == EOF){
            s[i]='\0';
            break;
        }
        if(ch == delimiter){
            s[i]='\0';//s[i]='\n';s[i+1]='\0'
            while('\n'!=(ch = fgetc(fp)) && EOF !=ch);//skip
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i==n-1)
        s[i] = '\0';
    return s;
}
```